# Can a polynomial be expressed as an infinite sum of non-polynomial functions?

Tags: functions, taylor-expansion

The Taylor series represents a non-polynomial function as an infinite series of polynomials, so is it possible to express a polynomial function as an infinite series of non-polynomial functions?

Comment: Random relevant comment: Taylor series are nice because you can write an arbitrary smooth function (which can be complicated) as a sum of polynomials (which are relatively simple).

Comment: Depends on you understanding of represents. Pointwise it is fairly obvious

Comment: @mathematician Do you count $e^{-1/x^2}$ as "arbitrary smooth"?

Comment: @Antitheos I define smooth to be whatever makes me correct ;)  So yes I should have said analytic.

Answer (score 17):

Without constraints on the functions, the answer is trivial. Take any family of non-polynomial functions $\phi_n(x),n>0$ such that their sum converges to some non-polynomial $\sigma(x)$.

Then define

$$\phi_0(x):=P(x)-\sigma(x)$$ and you have it:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\phi_n(x)=P(x).$$

---

The set of non-polynomial functions is much richer than that of polynomials, so there is no symmetry between Taylor and "reverse Taylor".

---

Another very simple example is the family of functions that equal the desired polynomial in range $[n,n+1)$ and zero elsewhere.

Answer (score 9):

Sure it's possible!  Take a simple fourier series.  One of my favorite:

$$x=\pi-2\left(\frac{\sin(x)}1+\frac{\sin(2x)}2+\frac{\sin(3x)}3+\dots\right)$$

For $x\in(0,2\pi)$.

$$y=-2\left(\frac{\sin(y)}1-\frac{\sin(2y)}2+\frac{\sin(3y)}3-\dots\right)$$

For $y\in(-\pi,\pi)$.

Comment: your Fourier series on the RHS is not a polynomial even though it is equal to $x$ on the interval $(0, 2\pi)$

Comment: @hyportnex Yes...?

Comment: the question was how to represent a polynomial not a *part* of a polynomial

Comment: Suppose you are looking at $x^2+2x-1$.  This is then trivial, since$$x^2+2x-1=\left(\pi-2\left(\frac{\sin(x)}1+\frac{\sin(2x)}2+\frac{\sin(3x)}3+\dots\right)\right)^2+2\left(\pi-2\left(\frac{\sin(x)}1+\frac{\sin(2x)}2+\frac{\sin(3x)}3+\dots\right)\right)-1$$

Comment: but the RHS is periodic and the LHS is not over the whole axis, so the two sides can equal only on a restricted interval, the RHS is not equal to a polynomial over the whole axis for polynomials (except for the constant) are never periodic functions.

Comment: @hyportnex And so?  I think my answer is fine, regardless of the fact that I had a domain restriction.

Comment: Even with a domain restriction just add a piecewise function that is equal to the rest of the polynomial outside of the domain the non-polynomial is defined on.  Since it's piecewise it's not really a polynomial.  It doesn't end up being the complete polynomial until the infinite series converges and thus should meet the requirements.

Comment: @Dason One may also point out that most series expansions have a limited radius of convergence to the original function, so nothing is unreasonable here.

Answer (score 7):

$\frac{x^2}{(1-x)^k}$ is not a polynomial for any $k>0$.

Yet $$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^2}{(1-x)^k} = -x
$$
is a polynomial.

If you want a series which converges on the entire real axis, try 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^2
\left(e^{x^2}-1\right)e^{-kx^2} = x^2
$$

Answer (score 3):

Here's an easy example. The hard part is actually just making sure none of the infinite number of functions in the sum is a polynomial, assuming you consider the zero function to be a polynomial.

Let $p(x)$ be an arbitrary polynomial. Then let
\begin{align}
f_0(x) &= \sin x \\
f_1(x) &= \begin{cases}  p(x)   & x < 0 \\
                        -\sin x & x \geq 0 \end{cases} \\
f_2(x) &= \begin{cases} -\sin x & x < 0 \\
                         p(x)   & x \geq 0 \end{cases} \\
f_n(x) &= \begin{cases} \dfrac{\sin x}{2^{n+1}} & \text{$n>2$ and $n$ odd} \\
                        \dfrac{\sin x}{2^n} & \text{$n>2$ and $n$ even}
          \end{cases} \\
\end{align}

None of these functions is a polynomial, since each function has an infinite number of zeros. But $p(x) = f_0(x) + f_1(x) + f_2(x).$

The functions $f_n(x)$ for $n > 2$ are defined in order to satisfy the requirement to express $p(x)$ as an *infinite* number of non-polynomial functions (which I think is the most difficult part of this problem). 
Each successive pair of functions has sum zero, so
$f_3(x) + \cdots + f_{2k}(x) = 0$ for any integer $k$.
For $n>2,$ therefore, 
the partial sum $f_0(x) + \cdots + f_n(x)$ is $p(x)$ if $n$ is even
and is $p(x) + \frac{\sin x}{2^{n+1}}$ if $n$ is odd.

The functions $\frac{\sin x}{2^{n+1}}$ converge to zero as $n\to\infty,$
so the sum converges to $p(x).$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the sum of the sequence of characteristic functions of all intervals [n,n+1) for all integers n. None of these functions is a polynomial, yet their sum is one.

Comment: Already said, more generally.